# Can I manually create migrations for production in Heroku, Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

I have created an application with Ruby and Rails. The thing is that when I was develpoing it, I had some problems with the migrations, because I created them but with a wrong syntax. What happened is that I deleted some of the files because sold migrations that didn´t work had the same name than the new ones, but in the middle of that I accidentally deleted some of the migrations (obviously after running rails db:migrate) that the project uses actually. So for instance, i have the Service table, which is related to the Reservation table because Service has reservation_id, but i don´t have the migration file that says AddReservationIdToService.

So now I want to use Heroku for production. the thing is that O have to change to postgresql because Heroku doesn't support sqlite. So i have to run the de:migrate again to create the tables and relationships in the new DB, but I need the files that I explained that I deleted. The question is:

Can I create the migrations manually, so when i run db:migrate for postgres the full structure of the database is created without lacking relations?

Comment: Migrations can be painful. My recommendation is to do `rake db:drop` and `rake db:create` `rake db:migrate` while you add/remove your migrations files until you get what you want. But do it locally first in your local environment with sqlite, and if you want change your current sqlite database name to another one so you don't delete your old db. Then, when you are able to do drop create and migrate with no errors, do it in your heroku db. Do you already have data in your heroku db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the migrations to recreate the existing DB -- in fact it's not a good idea to try for a couple of reasons (including the missing migration file problem you encountered). You can simply run:

```
bin/rails db:schema:load
```

to populate a new database from the existing schema. If for some reason you haven't got a db/schema.rb checked under version control you can run:

```
bin/rails db:schema:dump
```

against the sqlite version to re-create a fresh schema file from the database.

You can also keep your migrations list tidy by occasionally zapping really old migrations, since all the cumulative changes are captured in the schema file.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might create another couple of migration files.
Certify you have now the tables you wish locally with your sqlite. Draw these table in a piece of paper (or where it be the best fr you), then check this official [API documentation of Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).

Delete all migrations made before and create another according to the tables you drew.

The workflow is gonna be like:

1) "I need to create a table called Reservation, where is it shown on the documentation?"

2) "I need a table called Service, where is it shown on the documentation?

3) "I need to add a column with a foreign key to service named reservaton_id, how does this documentation says it?

For all this steps above, create the correspondent migration file as you normally have done.

The main difference here is not to run the migration locally. Instead, push your new version app to your heroku remote branch and **there** you run the migration, like:

`heroku run rails db:migrate`

Remember to not run this same migration locally because you already have these tables locally.

The last two advise is:

1) If your migration doesn't go as you expect, don't delete the migration file. Instead, run `rails db:rollback` and try again.

2) Keep tracking your migration files on the same branch of your version control.